# How can I get signaled by QSocketNotifier that a pipe is ready for reading?

Tags: python, windows, qt, unix, pyqt

Using Python 3.4, on Windows as well as Unix, I mean to use [QSocketNotifier](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSocketNotifier.html) to discover that a pipe is ready to read from. It's a kind of contrived example, since the pipe is used within a single process. Either way, the crux of the matter is that I need to act when there is something to read on the pipe.

I've come up with the following demo program, but QSocketNotifier never emits its [activated](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html#activated) signal. Am I missing something obvious?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import os


def can_read(fd):
   print('File {} can be read'.format(fd))


def start():
   print('Starting')
   reader, writer = os.pipe()
   notifier = QSocketNotifier(reader, QSocketNotifier.Read, w)
   notifier.setEnabled(True)
   notifier.activated.connect(can_read)
   os.write(writer, b'a')
   os.close(writer)


app = QApplication([])
QTimer.singleShot(0, start)
w = QMainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you written anything to the pipe?

Comment: @mdurant There's the `os.write` call in start().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In truth, this doesn't answer how to receive notifications from a readable pipe, but it does provide a cross platform alternative, i.e. monitoring a socket (instead of a pipe):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import socket

def _create_sock_pair(port=0):
    """Create socket pair.

    If socket.socketpair isn't available, we emulate it.
    """
    # See if socketpair() is available.
    have_socketpair = hasattr(socket, 'socketpair')
    if have_socketpair:
        client_sock, srv_sock = socket.socketpair()
        return client_sock, srv_sock

    # Create a non-blocking temporary server socket
    temp_srv_sock = socket.socket()
    temp_srv_sock.setblocking(False)
    temp_srv_sock.bind(('', port))
    port = temp_srv_sock.getsockname()[1]
    temp_srv_sock.listen(1)

    # Create non-blocking client socket
    client_sock = socket.socket()
    client_sock.setblocking(False)
    try:
        client_sock.connect(('localhost', port))
    except socket.error as err:
        # Error 10035 (operation would block) is not an error, as we're doing this with a
        # non-blocking socket.
        if err.errno != 10035:
            raise

    # Use select to wait for connect() to succeed.
    import select
    timeout = 1
    readable = select.select([temp_srv_sock], [], [], timeout)[0]
    if temp_srv_sock not in readable:
        raise Exception('Client socket not connected in {} second(s)'.format(timeout))
    srv_sock, _ = temp_srv_sock.accept()

    return client_sock, srv_sock


def can_read():
    print('Server can read')
    app.quit()


def write():
    print('Client writing')
    client_sock.send(b'a')
    client_sock.close()


app = QApplication([])

client_sock, srv_sock = _create_sock_pair()
notifier = QSocketNotifier(srv_sock.fileno(), QSocketNotifier.Read)
notifier.activated.connect(can_read)
write()

w = QMainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
srv_sock.close()
```

Comment: socket.socketpair isn't available on Windows.

Comment: Sorry, without a windows box, it seems I won't be able to test a solution for you.

Comment: Right. No worries though, I may just have found a solution.

Comment: I've pasted my working script, with an emulation of `socket.socketpair`.

Comment: Nice work! An additional thought: `select` can be used to monitor sockets in a non-blocking way instead of `QSocketNotifier`, may be simpler in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to do with letting the variables go out of scope. If you store all the relevant pieces, for example wrapped in a class, it works. Here is my solution (with pyqt4, my apologies), which runs until the window is closed:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import os

class win(QMainWindow):


    def can_read(self,fd):
       print('File {} can be read'.format(fd))


    def start(self):
       print('Starting')
       self.reader, self.writer = os.pipe()
       notifier = QSocketNotifier(self.reader, QSocketNotifier.Read, self)
       notifier.setEnabled(True)
       notifier.activated.connect(self.can_read)
       os.write(self.writer, b'a')
       os.close(self.writer)


app = QApplication([])
#QTimer.singleShot(0, start)
w = win()
w.start()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: PS: this was on linux - I wouldn't be surprised if pipe behaves differently under windows.

Comment: You're right about `reader, writer` going out of scope, ugh, but I'm still not getting the activated signal :( If it works for you, I guess it's due to platform differences.

Comment: Have you considered an actual socket rather than OS pipe? I know for sure these work on windows.

Comment: Actually yeah, I played with sockets just now indirectly (via asyncio), but couldn't get that to work either. If you could provide a working example, I will definitely try!